# `or` and `and` are of equal precedence in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Apparently `or` and `and` are of equal precedence in NetLogo. (See [Syntax](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#syntax) in Programming Manual.) Also, they are apparently left associative. So

```
true or true and false
```

returns `false`.

Is there a reason for that decision?

(The arithmetic operators have normal precedence.)

Answer (score 4):

Many programming languages give `and` higher precedence than `or`. As you've seen, NetLogo doesn't.

The decision certainly predates the open-sourcing of NetLogo in 2011.

I can't be completely sure, but I'm pretty sure the decision predates my involvement with NetLogo (which began in 2001). I don't recall anyone ever asking about this in the intervening years.

Very likely there isn't anyone who knows if this was the product of a conscious decision, or what. (There's a good chance it was simply copied from StarLogoT, which would put the original choice even farther into the dim recesses of the past.)

Making `and` higher precedence seems like a reasonable change to me. Perhaps at one time there would have been concern about compatibility with StarLogoT or UCB Logo, but that wouldn't matter anymore. Today, any compatibility concerns would have to do with existing NetLogo code.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it is changed. I ran into this because my program bombed out when I wrote it assuming `true or true and false` would return `true`. Any program that relies on the current implementation should be changed!

Comment: @RussAbbott You shd probably [open an issue](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues).

Comment: @Alan, Thanks for the suggestion and pointer. I submitted it.